# Appending to double Array method

Tags: java, arrays, string

So, I have a method like this

```
public String[][] getArgs(){
```

And, I want it to get results out of a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
```

But how do I append them to the array instead of just `return`ing them?

Comment: You're probably going to need 2 for loops

Comment: You can't "append" to an array; you can only allocate it and fill it.

Comment: You don't actually show what you're putting into the array...that would help a bit in dealing with the context.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `String[][]` array inside your method, fill this array inside a loop (or in any other way) and return that array in the end.

If you are sure you want to have only one `for` loop (instead of two, typical for 2-dimensional array), ensure your loop will go through the number of examples equal to the number of fields in your `String[][]` array. Then you can calculate the double-dimension array indexes from your single loop-iterator, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    int a = i % numberOfCollumnsInOutput;
    int b = i / numberOfCollumnsInOutput;
    String[a][b] = sourceForYourData[i];
}
```

(Of course which array dimension you treat as collumns (and which to be rows) depends on yourself only.) However, **it is much more typical to go through an n-dimensional array using n nested loops**, like this (example for 2d array, like the one you want to output):

```
for(int i = 0; i < dimensionOne; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < dimensionTwo; j++){
        array[i][j] = someData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your interest. A sample code according to Byakuya.

```
public String[][] getArgs(){

    int row = 3;
    int column =4;

    String [][] args = new String[row][column];    

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
            args[i][j] = "*";

    return args;
}
```

Comment: @MikeSamuel sorry for the mistake, the parentheses should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a LinkedList from that array, and then append the elements to it, and then create a new array from it. If you are not sure i'll post some code.